# What is the chance of Butt Stallion Giving an Orange item?

Tags: borderlands-2

I want to grind orange items, so I am deciding to battle the dragons over and over for ereidium, then feed Butt Stallion over and over. About how much ereidum will I need to get one orange item?

Comment: Oh crap I didn't know she gave items more than once. FWIW she gave me an orange first try (a Leech)

Comment: @BenBrocka, feed Butt Stallion 3 times in a row for the achievement "A Girl's Gotta Eat"

Comment: Relevant link: http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Butt_Stallion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems fairly random, but very low for a legendary item: From [testing](http://forums.gearboxsoftware.com/showthread.php?t=300702) that people have posted their results for:

```
Green Actions           774     45.21%
Blue Actions            584     34.11%
Purple Actions (Stone)  298     17.41%
Purple Actions (Purple)  54      3.15%
Legendary Actions         2      0.12%
--------------------------------------
Grand Total            1712    100.00%
```

And remember, each one of these drops is **5** eridium!